# HTML value change is caught by the event listener but the value doesn't change

Tags: javascript, html

```
<input id="spin-speed" type=number value="1" min="-10" max="10">
```

I have an input element on the HTML side,

```
const spinSpeed = document.getElementById("spin-speed")
spinSpeed.addEventListener("change", spin_speed.bind(null, spinSpeed.value), false)
```

And I have an event listener to the input element in question. But when I try to increment or decrease its value using the arrows provided by UI in the browser, its value isn't changed at all. On the other hand, when I debug the code, it is indeed caught by the event handler as expected. Put another way, the event handler sees the change but the value doesn't change. What should be done to fix it?

Comment: Could you put `spin_speed` implementation in the snippet?

Comment: Where are those arrows? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) one more time

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I didn't implement additional UI, the arrows are the default ones that are found in the <input>.

Comment: Just remove the second js line.

Comment: Does `value="1"` prevent the value from changing? When you say it's caught by the event handler, are you seeing a value other than 1 in the event handler or are you simply seeing that it was triggered?

Comment: It is triggered, just as you understand but it is not changing when I check it out from Console from Inspect navigator.

Comment: Try removing `value="1"` from your input element.